# Rowcolor in tabular vs Forest node, unwanted behavior

Tags: tables, forest, rowcolor

I have problems when using tabular and forest in the same document. The row colors is also active on nodes in Forest trees. See MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\rowcolors{2}{blue}{blue!20}         
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={box, rounded corners = 2pt}
 [Line one\\Line two\\Line three, fill=green, align=left, base=bottom
  [Line one\\Line two, fill=blue, text=white, align=left, base=bottom
    [Line one, fill=gray, align=left, base=bottom]
   ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
  \hline
  foo   & bar    & fubar \\
  fubar & toobar & foo \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: RowColor in Forest]

Comment: Yes, forest also uses tabular internally. Move the rowcolors behind the tree, and/or use grouping.

Comment: For multiline nodes, Forest uses tabular for formatting. Either you can limit the row colour definitions to the tabulars where you need them or you can switch them off for the trees where you don't.

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled. Please fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your example in order to

1. make it compile;
2. create an example which would make the effect of row colouring in the tree rather more obvious - if you fill the nodes with colours, that really makes it hard for other people to see the problem at a glance.

The example below includes trees with and without fills. I didn't reinstate you undefined key/style/whatever as I have no idea what it is meant to be.

Forest does not always use `tabular` internally but, as Ulrike says, it is using it internally in your code. This is because you are using the `align` key. Hence, anything which affects `tabular` environments will affect the nodes of your trees which use this option.

You can either switch colouring on when you want it (in, presumably, all `tabular`s) or switch colouring off when you don't (in, presumably, all `forest`s).

The first option is straightforward, so I demonstrate the second. In this case, we use a `default preamble` to overwrite the effect of `align`, after the tree is parsed and before it is typeset. We switch colouring off at the start of each affected node and on at the end.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{forest}
\rowcolors{2}{blue}{blue!20}
\makeatletter
\forestset{
  default preamble={
    before typesetting nodes={
      where={>Ot={align}{}}{}{
        content format={
          \noexpand\begin{tabular}[\forestoption{base}]{\forestoption{align}}%
            \noexpand\hiderowcolors
            \forestoption{content}%
            \noexpand\global\noexpand\@rowcolorstrue
            \noexpand\end{tabular}%
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={rounded corners = 2pt}
  [Line one\\Line two\\Line three, align=left, base=bottom
    [Line one\\Line two, align=left, base=bottom
      [Line one, align=left, base=bottom]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={rounded corners = 2pt}
  [Line one\\Line two\\Line three, fill=green, align=left, base=bottom
    [Line one\\Line two, fill=blue, text=white, align=left, base=bottom
      [Line one, fill=gray, align=left, base=bottom]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
  \hline
  foo   & bar    & fubar \\
  fubar & toobar & foo \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={rounded corners = 2pt}
  [Line one\\Line two\\Line three, align=left, base=bottom
    [Line one\\Line two, align=left, base=bottom
      [Line one, align=left, base=bottom]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={rounded corners = 2pt}
  [Line one\\Line two\\Line three, fill=green, align=left, base=bottom
    [Line one\\Line two, fill=blue, text=white, align=left, base=bottom
      [Line one, fill=gray, align=left, base=bottom]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: colouring really off - semi-off - on - really off - semi-off]

Comment: I do hope the OP is not planning on inflicting this colour scheme on a real audience.

Comment: Sure NOT! :) Just for showing what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This fixed my issue. And since the Forest package is using tabular internally I understand that my example was not an error but a known effect of that.

Comment: @JimmyWestberg :-) It is useful to know, actually, because you can do something like `align=lp{25mm}r` and use `&` to separate columns within the node. It is set up so when you write `align=left`, it is treated as `align=l`. Anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: This gives me this error though: **Unknown operator `O' or `Ot' (in '>Ot={align}{}'**

Comment: @JimmyWestberg You have an outdated version of Forest. Since the current version involves various bug fixes, updating is recommended. However, better do this by updating you TeX installation as a whole, rather than just Forest.

Comment: @JimmyWestberg I don't understand how it first fixed the problem and then caused an error, though. Do you have two installations of TeX?

Comment: It did fix the problem but caused multiple errors on a real Tex project and to many errors made the project not compile correctly. I understand that the package might need to be updated so that might fix the error. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @JimmyWestberg Well, probably the local group solution is best in that case. Sometimes, it is just easier that way ;).

Comment: @JimmyWestberg Probably Sašo could do it better ....

Answer (score 1):

A simple group together with an empty row color fixed my problem. Thanks for the help though!

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{forest}
\rowcolors{2}{blue}{blue!20}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={rounded corners = 2pt}
  [Line one\\Line two\\Line three, align=left, base=bottom
    [Line one\\Line two, align=left, base=bottom
      [Line one, align=left, base=bottom]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begingroup
\rowcolors{2}{}{}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={rounded corners = 2pt}
  [Line one\\Line two\\Line three, fill=green,align=left, base=bottom
    [Line one\\Line two, fill=blue, text=white, align=left, base=bottom
      [Line one, fill=gray, align=left, base=bottom]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\endgroup

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
  \hline
  foo   & bar    & fubar \\
  fubar & toobar & foo \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={rounded corners = 2pt}
  [Line one\\Line two\\Line three, align=left, base=bottom
    [Line one\\Line two, align=left, base=bottom
      [Line one, align=left, base=bottom]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begingroup
\rowcolors{2}{}{}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={rounded corners = 2pt}
  [Line one\\Line two\\Line three, fill=green, align=left, base=bottom
    [Line one\\Line two, fill=blue, text=white, align=left, base=bottom
      [Line one, fill=gray, align=left, base=bottom]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]